# How to make Firefox use the same proxy settings used by Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, proxy, http-proxy

I am using Chrome and Firefox. Due to proxy settings in Firefox it gives an SSL error, but Chrome works just fine.

How do I make Firefox use the same settings as Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

To make Firefox using the same IE or Chrome Proxy settings, In Firefox go to Options>Advanced then in Advanced options on the right click Network Tab then from the Connections section click on the Settings button, a popup window will open click use system proxy settings and click ok, that's it you're done.

To change Firefox settings back follow the same procedure on above and click No Proxy.. in the settings dialog box.